# OpenFoam downloading process

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and want to download OpenFoam on my computer. I am very new to this but I'm following instructions and the command `curl -s https://dl.openfoam.com/add-debian-repo.sh | sudo bash`
shown on the OpenFoam website isn't working. It returns nothing [as shown in the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Obpx.png)

```
hebah@DS033402:~$ curl -s https://dl.openfoam.com/add-debian-repo.sh | sudo bash
[sudo] password for hebah:
hebah@DS033402:~$
```

Comment: Where did you get that?  All it does is add a repo so why a script is needed is beyond me.  This is a security risk that is avoidable. Also this is the wiki on openfoam op ubuntu and has a lot more to say https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Installation/Linux/OpenFOAM-7/Ubuntu/20.04

Comment: I got it from https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/precompiled/debian I will try that next thanks.

Comment: Why pass some random text to `sudo bash`? You're giving some internet rando the keys to the kingdom. Always `curl -s https://dl.openfoam.com/add-debian-repo.sh | less` first. Then you can see what it's going to do, and figure out your next move. In your case, `sudo apt update;apt-cache search openfoam`